# Is steam authenticated possible without using OpenID?

Tags: php, authentication, steam

I'm wondering if it's possible to make an authentication system in PHP without using openID? I've done a few searches on google, but they're all using openID in some way. So, is it possible without openID, or does openID have some private api to steam? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Sites that require you to enter your Steam credentials are scams 99% of the time, and a terrible idea the other 1%.

Comment: @Sammitch steam allows you to login to a web site in the same way facebook, google, and StackOverflow allow you to login to a web site. not a bad idea at all, it's a pretty well defined, secure standard actually.

Comment: @JoshuaBurns I know. But this guy is asking about how he can get users to put *their* Steam credentials into *his* application for authentication and avoid having to use OpenID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to plug into Steam, then as far as I am aware, OpenID is your only option. If you're having trouble authenticating against OpenID, perhaps try one of these PHP libraries: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#php

Comment: It seems I am. Well, thanks for the link, I'll look into it.